# How to reduce size of existing network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have model based on MobileNet for regression task:

```
def MobileNet_v1():
    # Keras 2.1.6
    mobilenet = MobileNet(input_shape=(config.IMAGE_H, config.IMAGE_W, config.N_CHANNELS),
                          alpha=1.0,
                          depth_multiplier=1,
                          include_top=False,
                          weights='imagenet'
                          )

    x = Flatten()(mobilenet.output)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(config.N_LANDMARKS * 2, activation='linear')(x)

    # -------------------------------------------------------

    model = Model(inputs=mobilenet.input, outputs=x)
    optimizer = Adadelta()
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=mae_loss)

    model.summary()
    import sys
    sys.exit()

    return model
```

Network structure:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 128, 128, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)    (None, 130, 130, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 32)        864
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_bn (BatchNormalization (None, 64, 64, 32)        128
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_relu (Activation)      (None, 64, 64, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_1 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 66, 66, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_1 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 64, 64, 32)        288
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_1_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 64, 64, 32)        128
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_1_relu (Activation)  (None, 64, 64, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 64)        2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_1_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 64, 64, 64)        256
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_1_relu (Activation)  (None, 64, 64, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_2 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 66, 66, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_2 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 32, 32, 64)        576
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_2_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 32, 32, 64)        256
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_2_relu (Activation)  (None, 32, 32, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 128)       8192
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_2_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 32, 32, 128)       512
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_2_relu (Activation)  (None, 32, 32, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_3 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 34, 34, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_3 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 32, 32, 128)       1152
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_3_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 32, 32, 128)       512
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_3_relu (Activation)  (None, 32, 32, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 128)       16384
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_3_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 32, 32, 128)       512
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_3_relu (Activation)  (None, 32, 32, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_4 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 34, 34, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_4 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 16, 16, 128)       1152
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_4_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 16, 16, 128)       512
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_4_relu (Activation)  (None, 16, 16, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 256)       32768
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_4_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 16, 16, 256)       1024
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_4_relu (Activation)  (None, 16, 16, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_5 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 18, 18, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_5 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 16, 16, 256)       2304
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_5_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 16, 16, 256)       1024
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_5_relu (Activation)  (None, 16, 16, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_5 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 256)       65536
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_5_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 16, 16, 256)       1024
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_5_relu (Activation)  (None, 16, 16, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_6 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 18, 18, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_6 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 8, 8, 256)         2304
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_6_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 256)         1024
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_6_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 256)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_6 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 512)         131072
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_6_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_6_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_7 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_7 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_7_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_7_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 512)         262144
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_7_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_7_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_8 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_8 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_8_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_8_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_8 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 512)         262144
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_8_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_8_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_9 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_9 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_9_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_9_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_9 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 512)         262144
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_9_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_9_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_10 (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_10 (DepthwiseConv2D) (None, 8, 8, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_10_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_10_relu (Activation) (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_10 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 512)         262144
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_10_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_10_relu (Activation) (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_11 (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_11 (DepthwiseConv2D) (None, 8, 8, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_11_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_11_relu (Activation) (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_11 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 512)         262144
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_11_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_11_relu (Activation) (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_12 (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_12 (DepthwiseConv2D) (None, 4, 4, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_12_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 4, 4, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_12_relu (Activation) (None, 4, 4, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_12 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 1024)        524288
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_12_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 4, 4, 1024)        4096
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_12_relu (Activation) (None, 4, 4, 1024)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_13 (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 6, 6, 1024)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_13 (DepthwiseConv2D) (None, 4, 4, 1024)        9216
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_13_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 4, 4, 1024)        4096
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_13_relu (Activation) (None, 4, 4, 1024)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_13 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 1024)        1048576
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_13_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 4, 4, 1024)        4096
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_13_relu (Activation) (None, 4, 4, 1024)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 16384)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 16384)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 156)               2556060
=================================================================
Total params: 5,784,924
Trainable params: 5,763,036
Non-trainable params: 21,888
_________________________________________________________________
```

As we can see, about a half of network parameters is in last dense layer. So my question is if I have already trained network how to reduce model size? I have tested global average pooling instead of dense layer and for my regression task it performs poorly, so it's not an option, so I'm looking forward something like reducing dense layer size or sparsifying dense layer.

**Update:**

Example of network with global average pooling:

```
def MobileNet_v2():
    # MobileNet with GAP layer on top

    # Keras 2.1.6
    mobilenet = MobileNet(input_shape=(config.IMAGE_H, config.IMAGE_W, config.N_CHANNELS),
                          alpha=1.0,
                          depth_multiplier=1,
                          include_top=False,
                          weights='imagenet'
                          )

    x = Conv2D(filters=config.N_LANDMARKS * 2, kernel_size=(1,1), activation='linear')(mobilenet.output)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

    # -------------------------------------------------------

    model = Model(inputs=mobilenet.input, outputs=x)
    optimizer = Adadelta()
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=mae_loss)

    model.summary()
    import sys
    sys.exit()

    return model


_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 128, 128, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)    (None, 130, 130, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 32)        864
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_bn (BatchNormalization (None, 64, 64, 32)        128
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_relu (Activation)      (None, 64, 64, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_1 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 66, 66, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_1 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 64, 64, 32)        288
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_1_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 64, 64, 32)        128
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_1_relu (Activation)  (None, 64, 64, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 64, 64, 64)        2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_1_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 64, 64, 64)        256
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_1_relu (Activation)  (None, 64, 64, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_2 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 66, 66, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_2 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 32, 32, 64)        576
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_2_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 32, 32, 64)        256
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_2_relu (Activation)  (None, 32, 32, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 128)       8192
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_2_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 32, 32, 128)       512
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_2_relu (Activation)  (None, 32, 32, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_3 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 34, 34, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_3 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 32, 32, 128)       1152
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_3_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 32, 32, 128)       512
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_3_relu (Activation)  (None, 32, 32, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 128)       16384
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_3_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 32, 32, 128)       512
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_3_relu (Activation)  (None, 32, 32, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_4 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 34, 34, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_4 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 16, 16, 128)       1152
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_4_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 16, 16, 128)       512
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_4_relu (Activation)  (None, 16, 16, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 256)       32768
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_4_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 16, 16, 256)       1024
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_4_relu (Activation)  (None, 16, 16, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_5 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 18, 18, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_5 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 16, 16, 256)       2304
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_5_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 16, 16, 256)       1024
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_5_relu (Activation)  (None, 16, 16, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_5 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 256)       65536
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_5_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 16, 16, 256)       1024
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_5_relu (Activation)  (None, 16, 16, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_6 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 18, 18, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_6 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 8, 8, 256)         2304
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_6_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 256)         1024
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_6_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 256)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_6 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 512)         131072
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_6_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_6_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_7 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_7 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_7_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_7_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 512)         262144
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_7_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_7_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_8 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_8 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_8_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_8_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_8 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 512)         262144
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_8_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_8_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_9 (ZeroPadding2D)   (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_9 (DepthwiseConv2D)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_9_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_9_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_9 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 512)         262144
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_9_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_9_relu (Activation)  (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_10 (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_10 (DepthwiseConv2D) (None, 8, 8, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_10_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_10_relu (Activation) (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_10 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 512)         262144
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_10_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_10_relu (Activation) (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_11 (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_11 (DepthwiseConv2D) (None, 8, 8, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_11_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_11_relu (Activation) (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_11 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 512)         262144
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_11_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_11_relu (Activation) (None, 8, 8, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_12 (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 10, 10, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_12 (DepthwiseConv2D) (None, 4, 4, 512)         4608
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_12_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 4, 4, 512)         2048
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_12_relu (Activation) (None, 4, 4, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_12 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 1024)        524288
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_12_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 4, 4, 1024)        4096
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_12_relu (Activation) (None, 4, 4, 1024)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pad_13 (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 6, 6, 1024)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_13 (DepthwiseConv2D) (None, 4, 4, 1024)        9216
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_13_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 4, 4, 1024)        4096
_________________________________________________________________
conv_dw_13_relu (Activation) (None, 4, 4, 1024)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_13 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 1024)        1048576
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_13_bn (BatchNormaliz (None, 4, 4, 1024)        4096
_________________________________________________________________
conv_pw_13_relu (Activation) (None, 4, 4, 1024)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 4, 156)         159900
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 156)               0
=================================================================
Total params: 3,388,764
Trainable params: 3,366,876
Non-trainable params: 21,888
```

Comment: "I have tested global average pooling **instead** of dense layer", what do you mean by "instead"? You mean you have only added a global pooling layer at the end and no dense layer?

Comment: When you say the model performs poorly when you add a pool layer, what does it mean? For instance, Is the training loss still converging well, but the the val loss remains high (a.k.a overfit) or does the train loss remains too high (a.k.a underfit)?

Comment: I would try first to reduce dimensionality by applying another Conv2D layer with either a stride greater than 1 or smaller number of filters (which fits your case I believe). Then the last layer wouldn't have that much parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding reducing dense layer size:

> Compress the weight matrix W of an inner product (fully connected)
>   layer using truncated SVD

https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/tools/compress_net.py